# Output of Xpath Query

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

First I would like to ask what is the format of the output of the Xpath query.

For me when I do the view source of my output I get [view-source](http://pastebin.com/5h9Av6ur)

actual output - [output](http://pastebin.com/zXhwFcwW)

Sample xml - [xmlfile](http://pastebin.com/suhxzFhC)

My php code -

```
<?php

$variable=$_POST['module']; 
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
        $xmldoc->load('info.xml');

        $xpathvar = new Domxpath($xmldoc);

        $queryResult = $xpathvar->query("testcase[substring-after(
        substring-after(script, '/'),
        '/'
    ) = '$variable' or
    substring-before(
        substring-after(
            substring-after(script, '/'),
            '/'
        ),
        '/'
    ) = '$variable']"); 

foreach($queryResult as $var)
        {
                echo $var->textContent;
                echo "\n";
        }

?>
```

What I want is to get the string ending with .tcl instead of full content

pls help !!

Answer (score 0):

First you're looking only for a `testcase` element node, the actual path to the textcase nodes is `/testcaseInfo/testcase` and can be optimized to any testcase element in the document:

`//testcase`

Next to validate if an element ends with a string you copy that part of the string and compare it.

`//testcase[
  substring(
    script, 
    string-length(script) - string-length('.tcl') + 1
  ) = '.tcl'
]`

This will return the testcase element nodes, now you can use detail expression to fetch the data for each testcase:

Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$expression = "
  //testcase[
    substring(
      script, 
      string-length(script) - string-length('$module') + 1
    ) = '$module'
  ]
";

// iterate test test cases and get name/script strings contents
foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $testCase) {
  var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate('string(name)', $testCase),
    basename($xpath->evaluate('string(script)', $testCase))
  );
}
```

Output: https://eval.in/120110

```
string(59) "802.1x_2.52_RADIUS_Accounting_AVP_contains_client_static_IP"
string(31) "802dot1xRadAccAVPClntStatIp.tcl"
string(27) "802.1x_1.02_Basic_User_Mode"
string(25) "802dot1xBasicUserMode.tcl"
string(44) "802.1x_2.47_RADIUS_Accounting_Enable_Disable"
string(34) "802dot1xRadiusAccEnableDisable.tcl"
string(31) "802.1x_2.14_RADIUS_Assigned_CoS"
string(29) "802dot1xRadiusAssignedCos.tcl"
...
```

Comment: 1st I want to extract all those testcase which matches $variable content in the script tag.

After from that output i want to fetch the string ending with .tcl

Comment: 2ndly i only want to have 802dot1xRadAsgEgVlanId.tcl, 802dot1xRadAsgEgVlanName.tcl in the output !
not the full script tag .

Comment: I named the variable $module for semantics. Getting the last part would be easier in PHP, use a basename() on the script filename.

Comment: $variable=$_POST['module']; 

this variable contains the input given by the user which the Main module name.
After this I am suppose to fetch all those testcase content which have this $variable as the string appearing at 2nd position.
and thn from those testcase fetched in the previous query i want to get the testcase name which ends with the .tcl in the script tag.

Comment: Your question states "I want is to get the string ending with .tcl" - this would be the script element. I modified the answer to fetch testcase elements, iterate them and fetch detail data for each of them.