# Parsing the output of Xpath query

Tags: php, xml, xpath, nsxmlparser

I have the output of my xpath query like by using phhp code -

```
<?php

$variable=$_POST['module']; 
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
        $xmldoc->load('info.xml');

        $xpathvar = new Domxpath($xmldoc);

        $queryResult = $xpathvar->query("testcase[substring-after(
        substring-after(script, '/'),
        '/'
    ) = '$variable' or
    substring-before(
        substring-after(
            substring-after(script, '/'),
            '/'
        ),
        '/'
    ) = '$variable']"); 

foreach($queryResult as $var)
        {
                echo $var->textContent;
                echo "\n";

        }

?>
```

output -

```
Backup_Restore_04_Restore_mode_OFF_Restore 3630976 SDN_CONTROLLER scripts/testSuite/sdnSTC/Flare/Backup_Restore/Sprint16_tests/Backup_Restore_RestoreModeOFFRestore.tcl This test case is to verify Message on Restore mode OFF TCL STC OK 89765 NULL ALL SDN SDN_CONTROLLER target:system:family:stc-auto-workstation-B Backup_restore_05_restore_mode_on_No_Restore_file 3631050 SDN_CONTROLLER scripts/testSuite/sdnSTC/Flare/Backup_Restore/Sprint16_tests/Backup_Restore_RestoreModeOnNORestoreFile.tcl To verify Restore mode ON and there is no backupfile available for Restore and restart flare in normal mode TCL STC OK 89766 NULL ALL SDN SDN_CONTROLLER target:system:family:stc-auto-workstation-B
```

what i want is to get all the string ending with .tcl from this output.

How this can be done.
Pls help.. m stuck here since last 1 week :(

Comment: What is the data structure of `info.xml`?

Comment: Scuzzy - info.xml file is here :-

[xml](http://pastebin.com/suhxzFhC)

Comment: scuzzy - did u saw my output..
In that output i cant refer to script like this and so me stuck :(

Comment: Already answered that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401947/output-of-xpath-query/22402454#22402454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to have the output in the array you can do -

`foreach($queryResult as $var)
{
 $array[] = basename($var->getElementsByTagName('script')->item(0)->textContent);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
foreach($queryResult as $var)
{
  echo $var->getElementsByTagName('script')->item(0)->textContent;
  echo "\n";
}
```

Please change

```
$queryResult = $xpathvar->query("testcase
```

to

```
$queryResult = $xpathvar->query("//testcase
```

Comment: no i tried this and it gives me error :-

`Notice: Undefined property: DOMElement::$script in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 23`

Comment: Please review my edit, sorry I made the mistake of assuming SimpleXML

Comment: hey can you guide me about how can i just get the string ending with ".tcl" instead of full script tag ?

Comment: `echo basename($var->getElementsByTagName('script')->item(0)->textContent);`

Comment: btw y are you asking me to change

`$queryResult = $xpathvar->query("//testcase`

Comment: Yes, starting your xpath with `//testcase` means it will find any `<testcase>` in the XML document. Otherwise you could simply build a path from root such as `/testcaseInfo/testcase/`. Also I recommend using http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php